Power BI report - default time range problem


I have i date filter in my Power BI report (slicer type between). I need to configure it to default to show data for the last 8 months back from today's date.
I found an option to set up Filter type: relative date, Show items: is in the last 8 months , which works, but the problem is that I can't select in the from field an older date than the 8 months (I can only select from dates in the last 8 months, which is a bit strange behavior). How can I achieve the same result but with the option to choose any date (even older than 8 months etc).
